# How to evaluate the KNN classifier for each pair of variables?

Tags: python, validation, knn

I have used `permutatation_importance` to find which values are the most important

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance


columns=['progresion', 'tipo']

X = df_cat.drop(columns, axis = 1)
y = df_cat['progresion']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state = 42)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

knn.fit(X_train,y_train)

results = permutation_importance(knn, X, y, scoring='accuracy')

importance = results.importances_mean

for i,v in enumerate(importance):
   print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
```

But what I want to do is evaluate the KNN classifier for each pair of variables to find which pair of variables is more relevant to achieve a better performance of the model.

Answer (score 1):

kNN favors each independent variable (feature) the same. This makes it pretty difficult to isolate a feature using kNN or assign it a different weight.

Also since kNN is a non-parametric algorithm (it doesn't make any assumptions based on data), unlike Naive Bayes you can't get any meaningful probability output based on features.

In this case I would suggest taking a look at decision tree based algorithms such as random forests which inherently have a feature_importance_ as a builtin class in scikit-learn. This will give you the importance of each feature after implementing the model.

There is a great example here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html

Also RF feature_importance_ section here:
[Random Forest feature_importances_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_)

If you really want to go against the conventional wisdom and identify feature importance by using kNN algorithm one option can be to construct the model with different features and compare the overall accuracy later.

I know this may or may not be directly addressing your question. But it's what comes to my mind at the moment. Maybe there will be other answers with different angles than mine.